# Sencha Touch2: Display nested Json data in seperate row in list

Tags: javascript, json, listview, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch2, facing problem while displaying nested json data in seperate rows in list.
Here is my Json looks like:

```
[
    {
        "work": {
            "agent": {
                "activeFlag": "false",
                "shiftId": "0",
                "id": "0",
                "deleteFlag": "false"
            },
            "id": "124",
            "status": "Unassigned",
            "assignment": {
                "pnr": {
                    "locator": "ABCDEF",
                    "connectTime": "0",
                    "id": "0"
                },
                "id": "123",
                "alerts": "Delay",
                "customers": [
                    {
                        "lastName": "XYZ",
                        "firstName": "MNO"
                    },
                    {
                        "lastName": "PQR",
                        "firstName": "STU "
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "work": {
            "agent": {
                "activeFlag": "false",
                "shiftId": "0",
                "id": "0",
                "deleteFlag": "false"
            },
            "id": "124",
            "status": "Unassigned",
            "assignment": {
                "pnr": {
                    "locator": "ABCDEF",
                    "connectTime": "0",
                    "id": "0"
                },
                "id": "123",
                "alerts": "Delay",
                "customers": [
                    {
                        "lastName": "ANY",
                        "firstName": "KLJ"
                    },
                    {
                        "lastName": "CHE",
                        "firstName": "MAK"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

like this i have 30 'work' objects and in 1 'work' i have 1 'customers' array and i have multiple customers inside

I want to show 'customers' in seperate rows in list but am able to show all the customers of single 'work' in one row like.

```
Output should be:
---------------
delay
First Name: MNO
---------------
delay
First Name: STU
---------------
delay
First Name: KLJ
---------------
delay
First Name: MAK
---------------
```

here are models.
ModelList.js:

```
Ext.define('CustomList.model.ModelList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    xtype:'modelList',
    requires:['CustomList.model.Customers'],
    config: {
            fields:['work'],
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url:'http://localhost:9091/CustomListJson/app/store/sample.json',
            reader:{
            type:'json'

        }
    },
    hasMany:{model:'CustomList.model.Customers',
             name:'customers'}
    }

});
```

Customers.js:

```
Ext.define('CustomList.model.Customers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'firstName','lastName'
        ],
        belongsTo: "CustomList.model.ModelList"
    }

});
```

Here is my ShowList.js:

```
Ext.define('CustomList.view.ShowList',{
    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'showList',
    config:{
        layout:'fit',
        styleHtmlContent:'true',
        styleHtmlCls:'showListCls',
        items:[
            {
                xtype:'list',
                id: 'listitems',
                store:'StoreList',
            itemTpl:[ '{work.assignment.alerts}<br>',
                '<tpl for="work.assignment.customers">',
                'firstName: {firstName}<br>',
                '</tpl>'
            ]
 // am able get the below values in list
//                itemTpl:'{work.assignment.alerts}'
//                itemTpl:'{work.assignment.pnr.locator}'
//                  itemTpl:'{work.agent.activeFlag}'
//                itemTpl: '<b>{firstName} {lastName}     </b><br>'+'pnr: '+ '{locator}  <br>' +
//                    'Alerts: '+'{alerts}' +'status: '+'{status} '
               }]


    }
});
```

Here is my StoreList.js:

```
Ext.define('CustomList.store.StoreList', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:['Ext.data.reader.Json'],
    config:{
        model:'CustomList.model.ModelList',
        autoLoad:'true'

    }
});
```

Can anyone please help me. Thanks.

Comment: your missing a comma in your JSON

`"alerts":"Delay"
        "customers":[`

Comment: you also have a leading comma after your `assignment` object

Comment: updated the json file.

Comment: I added and answer then re-read your question, I think the answer i added is useless, are you trying to get a list item for every customer? did you need them grouped by work? can you give more detail in your question, you've posted a working solution and only given us a single sentence on what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were after?

[download here](http://george-gray.co.uk/images/Srinivas.zip)

[image: working screenshot]

This is a really simple mock up but it should help you out, I think you're model associations are confusing things.

List:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',

    config: {
        store: 'MyJsonStore',
        itemTpl: [
            '<div><div><h1>{work.assignment.alerts}</h1></div><tpl for="work.assignment.customers"><div>First Name: {firstName}</div></tpl></div>'
        ]
    }

});
```

store:

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyJsonStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        data: [
            {
                work: {
                    agent: {
                        activeFlag: 'false',
                        shiftId: '0',
                        id: '0',
                        deleteFlag: 'false'
                    },
                    id: '124',
                    status: 'Unassigned',
                    assignment: {
                        pnr: {
                            locator: 'ABCDEF',
                            connectTime: '0',
                            id: '0'
                        },
                        id: '123',
                        alerts: 'Delay',
                        customers: [
                            {
                                lastName: 'XYZ',
                                firstName: 'MNO'
                            },
                            {
                                lastName: 'PQR',
                                firstName: 'STU '
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                work: {
                    agent: {
                        activeFlag: 'false',
                        shiftId: '0',
                        id: '0',
                        deleteFlag: 'false'
                    },
                    id: '124',
                    status: 'Unassigned',
                    assignment: {
                        pnr: {
                            locator: 'ABCDEF',
                            connectTime: '0',
                            id: '0'
                        },
                        id: '123',
                        alerts: 'Delay',
                        customers: [
                            {
                                lastName: 'ANY',
                                firstName: 'KLJ'
                            },
                            {
                                lastName: 'CHE',
                                firstName: 'MAK'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        },
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'work'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

If you get the config working like I have then you can gradually add in your models and associations, as-well as your ajax loading, testing all the way, this should help you to discover what the issue is.

Also, you might want to consider using tools like [Json Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) when your working with JSON data, the original JSON blob you posted was difficult to read and badly formatted, all of which makes developing more difficult.

Comment: Thanks but I want to have firstName's in single rows ie.. list should have four rows.Updated my question.